# Maven cannot compile lambda expression

Tags: maven, lambda

I am new to maven and I am trying to compile a lambda expression.
When I run `mvn install` I get this error:

```
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I am using SDK version 1.8 as can be seen in this image:
[image]

And the code that causes the compile error is this (the error accures on line 11):
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your pom.xml which source version are you setting? Check also your compiler settings.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Apparently I didn't even know that I need to have a source version on the pom.xml file, thanks! It fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to set the source and target levels in you POM.

These can be smaller than the actual JDK you use.